# How do I create an ASCII string in OllyDBG?

Tags: ollydbg, debugging, debuggers

During the debugging process, I can use binary edit in order to add commands where I want, etc. However, I can't find any way to add an ASCII string at an address in which I can reference later. If I try to add something like: "hello", OllyDBG will just translate the bytes into commands and edit the assembly commands into the program.

Is there a way to just add the ASCII string into the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ollydbg v2

Ctrl+E  -> Ascii -> "Hello" -> Enter  and -> Ctrl+A    (to make ollydbg understand its string not code )
:(colon) Label for later Reference

use CTRL+G and type the label name for

here is a screen shot of a partially matched label that follows

[image]

```
CPU Disasm
Address                                Hex dump          Command              Comments
00D13FC0 This Is My Newly Added String 48 65 6C 6C 6F 00 ASCII "Hello",0;ASCII "Hello"
```

ollydbg 1 
RightClick -> Analysis -> During Next Ananlysis Treat Selection As Ascii String

Answer (score 1):

Most byte combinations make up valid opcodes. Its just a questions on how to interpret these bytes. You can use the hex view to check the bytes.

You can always use a hexeditor to modify data and code. If you want to 'add' the string, you may need to inflate the file and fix segment/section offsets of the file format you are using.

Possibly related question:
[Hexadecimal editing with and without ollydbg weird issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202472/hexadecimal-editing-with-and-without-ollydbg-weird-issue)